# How to match missing values with regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing, missing-data

I have a table (a string in this case) looking like this:

```
Community            Group / Access      context    acl_filter
---------            --------------      -------    ----------
Community_test-1      network-operator    C0n_text!  T3st-ACL#$
WEWORK                network-operator
RW                    network-admin       _C0n              
YANKS                 network-admin                  my_acl
```

I have to match and parse all the values using a SINGLE regex without using additional code, but I'm having problems to write a regex matching missing values too.

For now, let's ignore first two lines and focus on the actual values:

```
import re
import pprint

show_snmp_community = """
Community_test-1      network-operator    C0n_text!  T3st-ACL#$
WEWORK                network-operator
RW                    network-admin       _C0n              
YANKS                 network-admin                  my_acl"""

show_snmp_community_regex = "(?P<community>\S+)\s+(?P<group_access>\S+)\s+(?P<context>\S+)\s+(?P<acl>\S+)"
show_snmp_community_split = show_snmp_community.split('\n')
final_dict = {}
i = 0
for line in show_snmp_community_split:
    snmp_dict = {}
    match_snmp = re.match(show_snmp_community_regex, line)
    group_snmp = match_snmp.groupdict()
    community = group_snmp["community"]
    snmp_dict["community"] = community
    group_access = group_snmp["group_access"]
    snmp_dict["group_access"] = group_access
    context = group_snmp["context"]
    snmp_dict["context"] = context
    acl = group_snmp["context"]
    snmp_dict["acl"] = acl
    final_dict[i] = snmp_dict
    i += 1
pretty = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2, depth=10).pprint
pretty(final_dict)
```

Obviously, this results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriele\Desktop\prova.py", line 18, in <module>
    group_snmp = match_snmp.groupdict()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
```

While this is what I'd like to achieve:

```
{ 0: { 'acl': 'C0n_text!',
       'community': 'Community_test-1',
       'context': 'C0n_text!',
       'group_access': 'network-operator'}
1: { 'acl': '',
       'community': 'WEWORK',
       'context': '',
       'group_access': 'network-operator'}
2: { 'acl': '',
       'community': 'RW',
       'context': '_C0n',
       'group_access': 'network-admin'}
3: { 'acl': 'my_acl',
       'community': 'YANKS',
       'context': '',
       'group_access': 'network-admin'}}
```

I've tried many things with different regex, but without being successful :(

Comment: `(? P<context>\S+)` typo?

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because, when you split your original string into `show_snmp_community_split`, the first element is a blank string: `''`. This, when used with `re.match` returns `None`.

Use an if-statement inside the loop:

```
for line in show_snmp_community_split:
    snmp_dict = {}
    match_snmp = re.match(show_snmp_community_regex, line)
    if not match_snmp:
        continue
    group_snmp = match_snmp.groupdict()
    community = group_snmp["community"]
    snmp_dict["community"] = community
    group_access = group_snmp["group_access"]
    snmp_dict["group_access"] = group_access
    context = group_snmp["context"]
    snmp_dict["context"] = context
    acl = group_snmp["context"]
    snmp_dict["acl"] = acl
    final_dict[i] = snmp_dict
    i += 1
```

Next, since you have possibility of empty columns for `acl` and `context`, `\S+` matching in pattern would fail. Update the pattern to:

```
show_snmp_community_regex = "^(?P<community>\S+)\s+(?P<group_access>\S+)\s*(?P<context>\S*)\s*(?P<acl>\S*)$"
```

---

Output when tested locally:

```
┌─[hjpotter92]─[Oct 29, 2015]─[Programming]
└──$ temp.py
{ 0: { 'acl': 'C0n_text!',
       'community': 'Community_test-1',
       'context': 'C0n_text!',
       'group_access': 'network-operator'},
  1: { 'acl': '',
       'community': 'WEWORK',
       'context': '',
       'group_access': 'network-operator'},
  2: { 'acl': '_C0n',
       'community': 'RW',
       'context': '_C0n',
       'group_access': 'network-admin'},
  3: { 'acl': 'my_acl',
       'community': 'YANKS',
       'context': 'my_acl',
       'group_access': 'network-admin'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...doing so I obtain duplicate values for dictionary entries 2 and 3

Like: 

2: { 'acl': '_C0n',
       'community': 'RW',
       'context': '_C0n',
       'group_access': 'network-admin'},

Comment: That is because regex can not know how many spaces are you using for different columns.

Comment: So, am I asking something that cannot be achieved?

Comment: @Gabry_Jin It is possible, but not with regex alone.